# Linux command Git cloning dilemma

Tags: git, ubuntu, clone, root

I've been unable to clone a Git repository for for weeks due to the following problems:

First, I attempted a straight clone like the following:

```
git clone todd@project-1234.livecloud.hosting.acquia.com:todd.git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'todd'.: Permission denied
```

As I got a permission denied, I used `sudo`:

```
sudo git clone todd@project-1234.livecloud.hosting.acquia.com:todd.git
Cloning into 'todd'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

For the last two weeks I stopped there thinking something was obviously wrong with the source of the repo if sudo failed to work. I had uploaded my public SSH-KEY so I knew that was not the problem.

However, just out of curiosity, recently I set a password for my root user and logged in as root. I then issued a simple command to clone the repo and it simply worked without issue.

**I don't understand. If it worked as root shouldn't it have worked as a non-root user using sudo?** I'd appreciate any explanation/clarification.

Comment: Why are you using sudo and cloning as root instead of as yourself?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, `sudo` failed because it didn't had the correct ssh key. Which is not surprising since it's not the same user as "you", so it doesn't use the same private key.

I don't know why it succeeds now: maybe you / someone changed the private key of `root`, or added its public key on the git repo. (you could retry with `sudo` to check it out).

Anyway, the correct solution would likely have been to use `sudo` not to clone the repo, but to give your regular user the permissions to create a directory.